# SOQL to query Assigned Resource fields while using WorkOrder object

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, soql, aura-framework

I am trying to achieve following:

Select WorkOrderNumber, (Select AssignedResource.ServiceResourceId from AssignedResource), Subject,Description,Status,Job_Request_SDO__c,Job_Location__c,Job_Type__c,Job_Category__c,Job_Number_Text__c,CaseId From WorkOrder

I need ServiceResourceId  value from AssignedResource and rest of the query as it is so end results would provide me everything above. Even when i directly used AssignedResource.ServiceResourceId and also appending __r to it, query is throwing error.

Can someone kindly help on this case? I above query, if i can get ServiceResourceId value I am good. I do not want to use another method and query it. Should I use wrapper class to achieve above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT WorkOrderNumber, 
    Subject, 
    Description, 
    Status, 
    Job_Request_SDO__c, 
    Job_Location__c, 
    Job_Type__c, 
    Job_Category__c, 
    Job_Number_Text__c, 
    CaseId,
    (SELECT AssignedResource__r.ServiceResourceId__c 
      FROM AssignedResource) 
  FROM WorkOrder
```

That should do what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you for responding. I am facing below error.

FROM AssignedResource) 
           ^
ERROR at Row:12:Column:12
Didn't understand relationship 'AssignedResource' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.